# get string with dynamic variable from xml Strings

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to get a text from the string xml but with a dynamic variable. I explain. Generally we get a text of the form `R.string.name` from the `strings` xml, what I need is something like `R.string.variable`, where variable is an X value obtained from a database.

Any idea how i can do the above?

Comment: you could use dynamics strings, only declare in your xml file your string:      <string name="dynamic_string">Your dynamic value is = %s</string> and fetch your string using getString(R.string.dynamic_string, "yourValue")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get String dynamically use [`getIdentifier`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method in `Resources` class. You also need to provide package name.

**This is sample code in Kotlin:**

```
private fun getStringResourceByName(context: Context,  resourceName: String): String? {
    try {
        val packageName = packageName
        val resId = context.resources.getIdentifier(resourceName, "string", packageName)
        Log.i("Resource", "Resource Id: $resId")
        return getString(resId)
    }catch (ex : Exception){
        Log.e("Error", ex.message)
    }
    return null
}
```

Java Version:

```
private String getStringResourceByName(Context context, String resourceName) {
    try {
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "string", packageName);
        Log.i("Resource", "Resource Id:" + resId);
        return getString(resId);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("Error", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
val string = getStringResourceByName(this,"app_name")
```